# removing all Nodes on every level in multidimensional Array by KEY Name

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

This is one of these days .. tried a lot of possible solutions and starting to run in circles now. Hope someone can help me.

I retrieve a huge json file and need to remove all nodes (on every level) with a certain key.

I do have an array ($array) similar to this:

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => my title 1
                    [subtitle] => my subtitle 1
                    [pagetree] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [uid] => 1016
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [uid] => 1017
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [uid] => 4512
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [uid] => 1018
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [uid] => 1019
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [uid] => 1024
                                )
                        )

                    [languageVersions] => Array
                        (
                            [de] => Array
                                (
                                    [pid] => 1016
                                    [title] => Das ist der Titel in DE
                                    [subtitle] => german subtitle
                                    [pagetree] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1016
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1017
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 4512
                                                )

                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1018
                                                )

                                            [4] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1019
                                                )

                                            [5] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1024
                                                )
                                        )

                                    [tstamp] => 1410339721
                                    [package] => 1016/course_de
                                )

                            [jp] => Array
                                (
                                    [pid] => 1016
                                    [language_title] => Japanese
                                    [title] => This JAPANESE TITLE
                                    [subtitle] => Japanese SAub Title
                                    [pagetree] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1016
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1017
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 4512
                                                )

                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1018
                                                )

                                            [4] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1019
                                                )

                                            [5] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1024
                                                )
                                        ) 
                                    [tstamp] => 1405960286
                                    [package] => 1016/course_jp
                                )

                            [cn] => Array
                                (
                                    [language_id] => 19
                                    [pid] => 1016
                                    [language_title] => Chinese (simplified)
                                    [title] => Title Chinese
                                    [subtitle] => 
                                    [pagetree] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1016
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1017
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 4512
                                                )

                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1018
                                                )

                                            [4] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1019
                                                )

                                            [5] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [uid] => 1024
                                                )
                                        )

                                    [tstamp] => 1404520858
                                    [package] => 1016/course_cn
                                )

                            [th] => Array
                                (
                                    [language_id] => 29
                                    [pid] => 1016
                                    [language_short] => th
                                    [language_title] => Thai
                                    [title] => thai title
                                    [subtitle] => 
                                    [tstamp] => 1414136060
                                    [package] => 1016/course_th
                                )
                            )
                        )
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [uid] => 1657
                    [pid] => 2
                    [language_id] => 0
                    [language_short] => default
                    [language_title] => English
                    [title] => Dive Guide
                    [subtitle] => 
                    [pagetree] => Array
                        (

                                                        [0] => Array
                                (
                                   ....
```

I want to remove all Nodes on all levels with key [pagetree].

I found several posts here in StackOverflow regarding this problem, but could not manage to get them working ([Delete element from multi-dimensional array based on key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134824/delete-element-from-multi-dimensional-array-based-on-key/7134881#7134881), [Recursive search and remove in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053433/recursive-search-and-remove-in-array))

My Approach is:

```
function removeKeyFromArray(&$array, $key_to_remove) 
{ 
  foreach ($array as $key => &$value) 
  { 
    if (is_array($value)) 
    { 
      removeKeyFromArray($value, $key_to_remove); 
    } 
    elseif ($key==$key_to_remove)
    {
        unset($array[$key]);
    } 
  }
}


$json = file_get_contents('http://url.with.json.file');
$data = json_decode($json);
$array = objectToArray($data); 

removeKeyFromArray($array, 'pagetree');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

After the cleanup, the array should look like;

```
 Array
    (
        [result] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => my title 1
                        [subtitle] => my subtitle 1
                        [languageVersions] => Array
                            (
                                [de] => Array
                                    (
                                        [pid] => 1016
                                        [title] => Das ist der Titel in DE
                                        [subtitle] => german subtitle
                                        [tstamp] => 1410339721
                                        [package] => 1016/course_de
                                    )

                                [jp] => Array
                                    (
                                        [pid] => 1016
                                        [language_title] => Japanese
                                        [title] => This JAPANESE TITLE
                                        [subtitle] => Japanese SAub Title
                                        [tstamp] => 1405960286
                                        [package] => 1016/course_jp
                                    )

                                [cn] => Array
                                    (
                                        [language_id] => 19
                                        [pid] => 1016
                                        [language_title] => Chinese (simplified)
                                        [title] => Title Chinese
                                        [subtitle] => 
                                        [tstamp] => 1404520858
                                        [package] => 1016/course_cn
                                    )

                                [th] => Array
                                    (
                                        [language_id] => 29
                                        [pid] => 1016
                                        [language_short] => th
                                        [language_title] => Thai
                                        [title] => thai title
                                        [subtitle] => 
                                        [tstamp] => 1414136060
                                        [package] => 1016/course_th
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [uid] => 1657
                        [pid] => 2
                        [language_id] => 0
                        [language_short] => default
                        [language_title] => English
                        [title] => Dive Guide
                        [subtitle] => 
                        ....
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function removeKeyFromArray(&$array, $key_to_remove) 
{ 
  foreach ($array as $key => &$value) 
  { 
    if ($key==$key_to_remove) 
    { 
        unset($array[$key]);
    } 
    elseif (is_array($value))
    {
        removeKeyFromArray($value, $key_to_remove); 
    } 
  }
}
```

The way you did it would never find the keys to remove because they are arrays too so would go through the first part of the if/else statement all the time, hence never being unset.

Comment: Thank you! Small change with big effect :) Your Answer will be accepted as soon as I am able to - 5 more minutes...